# Rotating an image in Coldfusion and updating the file

Tags: coldfusion, image-rotation

I need to rotate an image in Coldfusion and then once rotated it updated the file with the new rotation. So far this is what I have:

```
<cfimage source="../imgupload/image1.jpg" name="myImage">
<cfset ImageRotate(myImage,90,"bicubic")>
<cfimage source="#myImage#" destination="image1.jpg" action="write" overwrite="yes">
<img src="../imgupload/image1.jpg" width="600">
```

However, when the file is displayed on the 4th line, it shows the original "non-rotated" image. Any help would be appreciated.

Regards Sam

Comment: You are writing the new image to a different folder, i.e. `destination="image1.jpg"`  <> `source="../imgupload/image1.jpg"`.

Answer (score 0):

Change the file path on line 3 or on line 4.

Since you are watching an image from the source folder

```
<cfimage source="../imgupload/image1.jpg" name="myImage">
<cfset ImageRotate(myImage,90,"bicubic")>
<cfimage source="#myImage#" destination="../imgupload/image1.jpg" action="write" overwrite="yes">
<img src="../imgupload/image1.jpg" width="600">
```

OR

```
<cfimage source="../imgupload/image1.jpg" name="myImage">
<cfset ImageRotate(myImage,90,"bicubic")>
<cfimage source="#myImage#" destination="image1.jpg" action="write" overwrite="yes">
<img src="image1.jpg" width="600">
```